# Supabase-Py: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers' when making client

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, supabase, supabase-database

I have been using supabase in python without problem but today I got an error when I went to create my client. Code is below, all help would be great.
Code

```py
from supabase import create_client, Client
supabaseUrl = 'REDACTED'
supabaseKey = 'REDACTED'
supabase = create_client(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey)
path_data = supabase.table('otto').select('*').execute()
print(path_data)
```

My Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "andrew_main.py", line 7, in <module>
    supabase: Client = create_client(supabase_url=supabaseUrl, supabase_key=supabaseKey)
  File "/home/garb/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/supabase/client.py", line 226, in create_client
    return Client(supabase_url=supabase_url, supabase_key=supabase_key, **options)
  File "/home/garb/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/supabase/client.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.postgrest: PostgrestClient = self._init_postgrest_client(
  File "/home/garb/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/supabase/client.py", line 185, in _init_postgrest_client
    client = PostgrestClient(rest_url, headers=headers)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using outdated versions of [postgrest-py](https://pypi.org/project/postgrest-py/) (< 0.5.0) and [supabase](https://pypi.org/project/supabase/) (< 0.1.1).

The error is likely caused by accidentally downgrading `postgrest-py`.

You should be able to fix this by running `pip install -U supabase`, which upgrades `supabase` (currently 0.5.3) and installs the compatible version of `postgrest-py` (currently 0.9.2).
<sub>*Omit the `-U` flag if you only want to install the compatible version of `postgrest-py` without upgrading `supabase`.*</sub>

## References

- [supabase-community/postgrest-py@1737e69](https://github.com/supabase-community/postgrest-py/commit/1737e698d1ab5c8b740acef8d506dfc56cac9ca9) (postgrest-py 0.5.0) started to accept `headers` in `PostgrestClient` `__init__`.
- [supabase-community/supabase-py@04bf6ef](https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-py/commit/04bf6ef1c854683b6ae1eb9b56b6273e147b2ed3) (supabase 0.3.0, depends on postgrest-py<0.9.0 and >=0.8.0) started to pass `headers` when instantiating `PostgrestClient`.
- [supabase-community/supabase-py@66db7d3](https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-py/commit/66db7d3d45e898242551543dca85431aa2101060) (supabase 0.1.1) switched to use `SyncPostgrestClient`; `PostgrestClient` was deprecated in `postgrest-py` 0.6.0.